# Beginner Level Java File Reading ArrayOutOfBounds Error

Tags: java, arrays, file, indexoutofboundsexception

I am new to java and I am trying to do an assignment where I have to read in data from a text file where the text file has the total number of items in the lists in the first line and the height, weight and the name data in the following. Since there are 5 data points, the first integer in the file is '5' and the following 5 lines are the respective datas that I am scanning.

it seems like I have trouble running this code from the command line but I can run it from netbeans. I am getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundExceptions:0 at bmi.Bmi.main<Bmi.java:18>
```

**Code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {      
   System.out.println("\nBMI Report:");
   File file = new File (args [0]);
   try{
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file));
            int count=scanner.nextInt();

            for(int i=0;i<5;i++){

            int height=scanner.nextInt();
            int weight=scanner.nextInt();
            String name=scanner.nextLine();
```

Comment: @john Did you pass the input to the program by `java <program_name> <file_location>` when executing from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundExceptions:0 at bmi.Bmi.main

This message means that element 0 was accessed, going beyond the bounds of the array, in other words the array is empty so this doesn't work.

This must be the problematic line in your pasted code:

> ```
> File file = new File (args [0]);
> ```

If args is empty, that will raise the exception as in your post. Your program requires an argument. Of you pass it an argument, that should resolve your problem.

You might want to add a check first and print a helpful message, for example:

```
if (args.length < 1) {
    System.out.println("You need to specify an argument. Bye.");
    System.exit(1);    
}
File file = new File (args [0]);
// ...
```